# How can I re-enable the shift key?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu

Sometimes my shift key does not work at all in Kubuntu 17.04. How can I re-enable it?

This is not a hardware problem: no problem with other operating systems, and the problem is only on my user account, but I have the same problem with other keyboards.

No problem with others keys (my keyboard is a logitech k120, Italian)
Remapping keys? I tried `xmodmap -e "keycode 50 = Shift_L"`  but it didn't work.

Comment: i think that the problem is find where are storde user keyboard settings in kde plasma 5, because as other user shift key is working fine